# Sort files in the correct order

Tags: powershell

I want to sort somes files in the correct order for selecting them later by using a grid. For this, I use this command :

```
 $choose = Get-ChildItem $environment\Aither\Srv\Ptah\Tables\*.sql -Filter "*patch_5*.sql" -File | 
    # sorted by a calculated name
    Sort-Object { if ($_.BaseName -match '(.+-RC)(\d+)$') { '{0}{1:D3}{2}' -f $matches[1], [int]$Matches[2], $_.Extension }
                  else { '{0}-RC999{1}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.Extension } } |
    Out-GridView -Title "Select your files" -OutputMode Multiple
    $choose
```

I obtain that :

[image]

The files are sorted well by placing the RC files after those which do not have them. However, I have a problem, the old files are misplaced and I wanted to know if it was possible to sort them while keeping the RCs placed after.

Example before :
patch_5.0.10 ;
patch_5.0.11 ;
patch_5.0.5 ; ...
patch_5.1.0-RC2 ;

Desired example :
patch_5.0.5;
patch_5.0.10;
patch_5.0.11;...
patch_5.1.0-RC2 ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a calculated file name to sort on.
Depending on how many revisions you may have, I guess it is also importand to sort these numerically correct.

Lets say you have a set of files that would (without sorting) look like this in the gridview:

[image]

Then to sort the way you want, and numerically correct you need to do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\Test' -Filter "*patch_5*.sql" -File | 
    # sort by a calculated name
    Sort-Object { if ($_.BaseName -match '(.+-RC)(\d+)$') { '{0}{1:D3}{2}' -f $matches[1], [int]$Matches[2], $_.Extension }
                  else { '{0}-RC999{1}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.Extension } } |
    Out-GridView -Title "Select your files" -OutputMode Multiple
```

Output in GridView:

[image]

<sup>The above assumes you do not have more than 998 revisions.. If you have more, change `{1:D3}` to a higher number of digits like `{1:D4}` in the `if` block and change the hardcoded `RC999` to an equally highest number like `RC9999`</sup>

Comment: you are the boss Theo

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating an additional property containing only the information you're after. Something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem path\*.sql -Filter "*patch_5*" | 
Select-Object -Property *;@{Name='Version';Expression={[Version]($_.BaseName -split '_')[1]}} |
Sort-Object -Property Version | 
Out-GridView -Title "Select your files" -OutputMode Multiple
```

This way you should get a proper sorting for the version part of the file name.